# How to integrate AppOpenAd from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to integrate AppOpenAd in my current application but i am confuse How to integrate it.

My application flow is Splash Screen -> Display AppOpenAd -> Home Screen.

Below is code:

```
import { AppOpenAd, TestIds, AdEventType } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.APP_OPEN : 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

const appOpenAd = AppOpenAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
  keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
});

appOpenAd.load();

appOpenAd.show();
```

Please suggest any advice.

Thank You.